# What is darkoct02 on title?

Tags: wordpress

My site title has been changed to "darkoct02". My site is wordpress. I dont know where it is come from, any one know what is it? I searchrd google and I found many site have this title

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your website is hacked.
And by using `wp_content_injection` they change your title to `DarkOct02`

Comment: Could it affects permanently? I mean could it change any thing else in site?

Comment: I think it is better to check `wp-config.php` and `.htaacess` to see if these files are affected. and than in `wp-content/uploads/` disable running `.PHP` by creating an `.htaacess` inside this folder. and next step check your database->`wp-options` table.

Comment: Also, please check the root file and compare it with lean WordPress to see if any additional files are created inside the root. later it is better to replace `wp-admin` and `wp-include` folder with new version.

Comment: I am faced with the same issue. I don't know how it was fixed. darkoct02 automatically disappeared. @SallarRabiei do you know how this could happen? What is so vulnerable in the site that helped it get hacked? wp-config and htaccess are not updated.